# Wordpress not accessable after changing http to https

Tags: wordpress

I just changed the "Wordpress address" and "Site address" Urls of my wordpress from `http` to `https` under settings. After clicking save, the site reloaded and wasnt reachable anymore. I tried replacing the url with https, but same thing happens.

> This site can’t provide a secure connectionlocalhost sent an invalid
> response. ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR

I cant undo the changes because I cannot access the site.
I cant find any info or similar issues. What am I doing now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find your wp-config.php, then add the 2 lines at the bottom of the example below to force it back to http.

This should allow you access to your Admin page while you work out the issues.

Make sure to replace "http://www.example.com" with your own domain name.

```
<?php
define( 'WP_CACHE', true );

/**
 * The base configuration for WordPress
 *
 * The wp-config.php creation script uses this file during the installation.
 * You don't have to use the web site, you can copy this file to "wp-config.php"
 * and fill in the values.
 *
 * This file contains the following configurations:
 *
 * * Database settings
 * * Secret keys
 * * Database table prefix
 * * ABSPATH
 *
 * @link https://wordpress.org/support/article/editing-wp-config-php/
 *
 * @package WordPress
 */

define('WP_HOME','http://www.example.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://www.example.com');
```